# exiftool from Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, exiftool

I am trying to use exiftool form Cocoa

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ExifTool.h"   //  this is a .mm file so that we can include C++ code/structures

@implementation MyClass

-(id)myInit
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        ExifTool* tool = new ExifTool("/Users/trygve/Tools/exiftool");
    }
 }
```

This is obviously just a test but in the "new ExifTool" line I get a crash:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
    0x7fff5fc01074 <+0>: int3   
->  0x7fff5fc01075 <+1>: nop    

Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN8ExifToolC1EPKcS1_
```

The following code works fine in a straight C++ terminal program. This is from the examples on the exiftool developer page. Why does this code work fine, but when I try to use it from a Cocoa .mm file, it does not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ExifTool.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Example1: Read metadata from an image." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Please specify input file name" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // create our ExifTool object
    ExifTool *et = new ExifTool("/Users/trygve/Tools/exiftool");
    // read metadata from the image
    TagInfo *info = et->ImageInfo(argv[1],NULL,5);
    if (info) {
        // print returned information
        for (TagInfo *i=info; i; i=i->next) {
            std::cout << i->name << " = " << i->value << std::endl;
        }
        // we are responsible for deleting the information when done
        delete info;
    } else if (et->LastComplete() <= 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error executing exiftool!" << std::endl;
    }
    // print exiftool stderr messages
    char *err = et->GetError();
    if (err) std::cerr << err;
    delete et;      // delete our ExifTool object
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `exiftool` is a perl program so it's not clear what it is you've got at `"/Users/trygve/Tools/exiftool"`.

Comment: I have the exiftool command line program as downloaded from the exiftool site (it works fine in terminal). I am using it based on the docs and code here: http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/cpp_exiftool/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the C++ code files associated with this were getting copied into the app rather than compiled. It works as expected. With just the header files there was no error, and a pretty cryptic crash.